# loopback after delete customize the result sent to client

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In my loopback application i have to customize the delete result sent to the client.

```
xxxxx.observe('before delete', function(ctx, next) {
      xxxxx.find({
          where: {
            id: ctx.where.id
          }
        }, function (err, transaction) {
            if(yyyy.length > 0){
                var id = yyyy[0]['id'];
                pgclient.query("delete from qqq where kkkk = '"+id+"' ", function(err, dbRes){
                  if(err){
                    next(err);
                  } else{
                    next();----------------> here i have to customize the result
                  }
                });
            } else {
                next({"message":" for the given id"});
            }
        });
    });
```

Now the result sent to client is:

```
{
  "count": 1
}
```

But i need to modify this as:

```
{"message":"Deleted Successfully"}.
```

I tried a lot regarding this, but no result. Please share your ideas.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with minimal code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Like, what is in next() and what happens if you change next() to next({'message':'some message'}) ?

Comment: So if you change next() to next("message":"Deleted Successfully") is it not sending that message?

Comment: You are working in loopback right??so that  i can explain more deeply..

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is operation hook and `next` callback is just for determining successful/failure of operation.

For customizing messages you should do in remote method or remote hooks